# Send parameter values to servlet file from jsp using data table jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, datatables

I used datatables plugin to implement a data table in a javaEE web application.
Now i try to pass some parameters to servlet file from the jsp file using data table plugin.but it did not work yet.can u provide a simple example to this ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setParam(){
        $('#example').dataTable( {
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "./AccountSummary",//servletname
            "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
                alert("A");
                aoData.push( { "name": "a", "value": "b" } );
            }
        } );
    }
</script>
```

function call in here

```
<div>
    <input type="button" onclick="setParam()" value="click">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the datatables initialisation code out of the function.  The way you're doing it just reinitialises the table.

```
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
     "bProcessing": true,
     "bServerSide": true,
     "sAjaxSource": "./AccountSummary",//servletname
     "fnServerParams": function ( aoData ) {
           alert("A");
           aoData.push( { "name": "a", "value": "b" } );
      }
 } );
```

Give your button an id:

```
<div>
    <input type="button" id="mybutton" value="click">
</div>
```

Call [fnDraw()](https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnDraw) on the button click event:

```
$('#mybutton').click(function (e) {
    oTable.fnDraw();
});
```

You haven't said where parameters `name` and `value` come from, but this will pass `a` and `b` in the server request